# zend framework table relationships, referenceMap & dependentTables

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

I'm new to zend framework, i'm trying to understand how table relationships work. I have two tables and i'm trying to link them and get their data in a list.

```
CREATE TABLE  `relationship` (
  `relationship_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `relationship_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `relationship_group_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `display` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`relationship_id`),
   KEY `FK_relationship_1` (`relationship_group_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_relationship_1` FOREIGN KEY (`relationship_group_id`) REFERENCES     `relationship_group` (`relationship_group_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE  `relationship_group` (
  `relationship_group_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `relationship_group_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `display` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`relationship_group_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

In my relationship table class, I have:

```
class Relationship_Table extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_rowClass = 'Relationship';
    protected $_name = 'relationship';
```

In my relationship group table class I have:

```
class Relationship_Group_Table extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
protected $_name = 'relationship_group';
protected $_rowClass = ' Relationship_Group';
```

I am not sure what my $_referenceMap and $_dependentTables should say, and if I need to state them in both classes or just one?

Also how do I get a list from my relationships table with the corresponding relationship_group data included.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pretty good primer on table relationships. 
[Mat McCormisck on Table relationships in Zend Framework](http://mattmccormick.ca/2010/04/24/how-to-easily-create-models-and-table-relationships-in-zend-framework/)

The actual answer to your question is:

- It depends on what you need to accomplish and how do you want to accomplish it.

Comment: +1, Thanks for very interesting blog post. It cleared my suspicions :)

Answer (score 0):

`$_dependentTables` aren't required in your case (using InnonDB).

> [Zend References](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.db.table.relationships.html#zend.db.table.relationships.defining)
>
> Note: Skip declaration of `$_dependentTables` if you use referential integrity constraints in the RDBMS server to implement cascading operations

Your `$_referenceMap` should link `FOREIGN KEY` in a dependent table to the `PRIMARY KEY` in the parent table and it's only required in the dependent table.

The rest is as RockyFord suggested in his link :).